# Springboot Entity add field that is not stored in database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I can store file in my application and I want to be able to know if a file is uploaded or not. I do not want to store the information saying if the file is uploaded or not in the database for some reasons.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "files")
public class files {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    private boolean uploaded;
}
```

To know if a file is uploaded or not, I have a method in StorageService :
`storageService.exists(path);`

Is it possible to add the information with StorageService or I need to store it in DB ?

I also want to know if there is a best practice.

Comment: Mark it with `@Transient`.

Comment: Ok but how to populate it with the method ?

Comment: Call it and set it. Somewhere in your service method.